# Время работы скрипта на сервере

Tags: php, сервер, хостинг, синтаксический-анализ

Вот такой вопрос! Значит, есть готовый парсер на сервере, но он ни в какую не хочет работать, т.е. время работы скрипта на сервере ограничено установкой лимита времени `set_time_limit()`, а задача требует, чтобы парсер работал сутками и обновлял информацию! Может, подскажите, как заставить работать скрипт? Ведь на локальном сервере у меня все работает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По порядку.

Для запуска скрипта на сервере с условно-бесконечным или просто большим временем выполнения надо так или иначе запускать его как консольный скрипт. Сервер - программа, которая не предназначена для того, чтобы один из ее воркеров выпла на *условное навсегда*, если парсер запускается в рамках обычного веб-запроса, то сервер вынужден делегировать один из своих потоков этому парсера, и ждать, когда он отработает (никогда). Если страница тридцать секунд не может вернуть ответ, значит, стоит вернуть ошибку ожидания пользователю. Вопрос не говорит о методе запуска скрипта, поэтому я на всякий уточнил.

*Как запустить скрипт из консоли?* Очень просто: подключиться к терминалу сервера и выполнить этот скрипт с помощью php: `php script.php`. В этом случае:

- Не убивается воркер веб-сервера и вообще не участвует внешняя оболочка скрипта
- По умолчанию max execution time неограничено
- Не нужно форматировать вывод как html, плюс можно логировать вывод средствами самой ОС.

Это обеспечивает только одноразовый запуск скрипта, зато висеть он может хоть бесконечно.

*Как регулярно запускать скрипт?* Как ответили выше - по крону (планировщику заданий). 99%, что на сервере установлен linux, а значит планировщиком является cron. Подробную документацию вы найдете в интернете, задания редактируются с помощью `crontab -e` или в панели хостера и представляют из себя время выполнения и команду, которую необходимо исполнить - точно такую же, как в примере выше. Таким образом cron поможет запускать скрипт каждые N минут или гарантировать его перезапуск в случае падения.

*Как убедиться, что скрипт отработал перед тем, как запускать его снова?* Вот тут начинает прорастать филигранная работа. Проще всего оставлять некий .lock-файл при начале работы скрипта и затирать его в конце - в этом случае повторно запущенный скрипт проверит наличие файла, увидит его существование и откажется запускаться. Для того, чтобы избежать ситуаций, когда скрипт упал, а .lock-файл остался, можно записывать туда PID (идентификатор процесса). В этом случае повторно запущенный скрипт опрашивает ОС на предмет наличия процесса с таким PID, и если последний существует, то необходимо прекратить работу.

Comment: @Etki "подключиться к терминалу сервера" - не понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду? Как подключится к терминалу сервера?

Comment: @ggLike скачиваем `putty`, запускаем, вводим ip сервера, подключаемся, вводим данные пользователя, выполняем действия.

Answer (score 2):

Такие задачи решаются через [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю! А если еще добавить псевдопотоки путем CURL.

Comment: @kostyanet поясните, как работает cron в php, ссылку на wikipediю я тоже могу поставить!

Comment: Не cron  в php, а php в cron. Cron - это такая системная программа (если говорить просто), которая умеет запускать любые программы по заданному расписанию. Можно, к примеру, попросить запускать каждую вторую пятницу в 4 и 5 часов ночи.

Если Ваша программа с консоли умеет запускаться, то обычно нет никаких проблем ее запустить с крона.

Answer (score 1):

```
$start = microtime(true);  
# ...  
$time = microtime(true) - $start;  
printf('Скрипт выполнялся %.4F сек.', $time);
```

Может, сделать, чтобы скрипт выполнял свои действия порциями и дергался кроном.

Comment: @NMD сможете объяснить на примере? 
вот логика: 
парсинг ссылкок категорий в массив 
цикл 1
в цикле формируем данные подкатегории
также парсим информацию ссылки подкатегорий, наименование и тд. 
дальше еще один цикл 2
в ней формируются данные к запросу для скачки файла
дальше цикл 3 
потом парсится файл скрипт разбивает в 
цикле 4
потом запись в базу 
закрытие цикла 4
закрытие цикла 3
закрытие цикла 2
закрытие цикла 1 
Вот такая вот ерунда, противно то что нельзя по другому сделать ( можно но времени нет ) 
сможете подсказать как задействовать ваш метод?

Comment: $start = microtime(true);  
цикл 1
$time = microtime(true) - $start;  
$start = microtime(true);  
цикл 2
$time = microtime(true) - $start;  

и так по аналогии?